# selenium not returning any output

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website for reviews but unable to do so.

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/hp/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

```
driver.get("https://www.sephora.com/product/luminous-silk-foundation-P393401?skuId=1491380&icid2=products%20grid:p393401:product")
reviews = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"css-k7hahd eanm77i0")
for review in reviews:
    post = review.text
    print(post)
```

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 Can you link the previous question please?

Answer (score 0):

That page is loading dynamically, depending on user's input. For instance, to load the reviews, you need to scroll the page down.
One way (there surely are other ways as well) of retrieving the reviews, with selenium and BeautifulSoup, is exemplified below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url='https://www.sephora.com/product/luminous-silk-foundation-P393401?skuId=1491380&icid2=products%20grid:p393401:product'

browser.get(url) 

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
t.sleep(5)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
t.sleep(5)
reviews_tab = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"ratings-reviews-container")))
random_review = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"eanm77i0")))

soup = BeautifulSoup(reviews_tab.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'html.parser')
print([x.text.strip() for x in soup.select('div.eanm77i0')])
browser.quit()
```

There are other, more efficient ways than selenium to retrieve the reviews in this case.

Comment: what is the more efficient way to do it  ? @platipus_on_fire_333